# Преобразование изображений

Tags: jquery, php

У нас есть большое изображение. Как преобразовать его с помощью JQuery? Например сделать меньшим по размеру и тд. Какую именно библиотеку следует использовать? Или например такое - как в контакте - нажали на картинку и она отобразилась на темном фоне большего размера.
Рекомендовать бесплатные библиотеки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете использовать галерею [FancyBox](http://www.fancybox.net/).

Только там все на английском языке, а на русском могу посоветовать вот это: [FancyBox - фотогалерея + модальные окна](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=238).

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто стилями уменьшить изображение и в javascript коде на событии **onclick**

Накинуть тень и показать во весь размер...

Answer (score 0):

Как в контакте: [Оформляем картинки с помощью jQuery](http://wphelp.ru/2010/image-hover-text-jquery.htm).